# Using a LINQ Where clause to filter by data in an associated table

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, join, intellisense, model-associations

I have two tables, Articles and Statuses that I have associated in a ctx.dbml file.

```
Articles
id:int
title:varchar(255)
status_id:int

Statuses
id:int
name:varchar(255)
```

What I'd like to do is filter all of the articles of a certain status. Hypothetically speaking, something like:

```
var filteredArticles = from article in ctx.Articles
                       where article.Status.name == "Active"
                       select article;
```

The issue that I'm having is that in the above linq query, second line, Intellisense never gives me *article.Status.name*. I've seen code on the internet like this, so I must be missing something. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do it like you want, you have to set up an association between the two tables.

[How to: Create an Association (Relationship) Between LINQ to SQL Classes (O/R Designer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629295.aspx)

Alternatively, you can just write the join manually.

```
var activeArticles = from a in ctx.Articles
                     join s in ctx.statuses on a.status_id equals s.id
                     select a;
```

If you go the association route, be very careful that you don't commit the SELECT N + 1 error.

Comment: Argh! I had the association set up backwards. Thanks.